# I want to know about izettle payment method for android

Tags: android, payment

I Have research on this and found the izettle developer site
https://www.izettle.com/developer it sdk available for IOS but not getting any demo or material for android sdk. please give a way and need to understand of it, izettle is provide sdk for android if yes then how to integrate with android is there any demo link or else please help i am new with izettle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in official site https://www.izettle.com/developer

> **Developer SDK for Android** 
>  We're hard at work on this still, but please leave your email if you'd like early access.

[image]

So there are only 2 options

**1) Write your email id at their android SDK section (as given in the above image)**

**2) You have to wait until they release their official SDK**